# Возвращение из функции &&

Tags: c++, c++11

В популярной статье заметил подобный код:

```
int&& f()
{
      return 2;
}
```

Тут xvalue, но на временную переменную в стеке функции. Он будет не корректен, правильно? Знаю что &&/const& продлевают жизнь (12.2/5), но не в таком контексте же:

```
const int& f()
{
     return 2;
}
```

Может быть, в первом коде, какой то трюк с литералом и xvalue?

(Этот код должен быть некорректным, но статья популярней меня)

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11` тоже ругается на него -- `c.cpp:9:14: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
       return 2;`, однако код собранный без оптимизации выводит 2, тогда как с оптимизацией очевидно ошибочное `32764`.  Возможно не всем статьям в сети (даже популярным) стоит доверять?

Comment: @avp , я сомневался, задал вопрос. Если статья была непопулярной, я бы не задавал вопрос.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы убедиться, что функция некорректна, можно запустить следующую тестовую программу

```
#include <iostream>

struct Int
{
    Int( int x ) : x( x ) { std::cout << "Int::Int( int )" << std::endl; }
    ~Int() { std::cout << "Int::~Int()" << std::endl; x = 100; }
    Int( const Int &rhs ) : x( rhs.x ) { std::cout << "Int::Int( const Int & )" << std::endl; }
    Int( Int &&rhs ) : x( rhs.x ) { std::cout << "Int::Int( Int && )" << std::endl; }

    int x;
};   

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const Int &rhs )
{
    return os << rhs.x;
} 

Int && f()
{
    return 2;
}

int main()
{
    Int x = f();

    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль может выглядеть следующим образом (хотя из-за неопределенного поведения программы вывод может отличаться)

```
Int::Int( int )
Int::~Int()
Int::Int( Int && )
x = 100
Int::~Int()
```

Как видно в функции main переменная x получила значение уже удаленного объекта.

Comment: Круто! А можно ссылку на стандарт?

Comment: @VladD В принципе достаточно указать следующую цитату из раздела  3.7 Storage duration "3 The storage duration categories apply to references as well. The lifetime of a reference is its storage duration." Поэтому ссылка на объект время существования которого закончилось, является недействительной.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!